# What is the change in velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity, vectors

A boat moves with a velocity of 22 m/s directly west. Later, the boat is found to have a velocity of 12 m/s at 45° S of W. What is the change of velocity? I want to do this vector wise. I know that the change of velocity, delta v = v(final) - v(initial) => delta v = vf + (-vi).

However, I only know how to solve the examples where objects move either vertically or horizontally.

I used Pythagoras theorem to get the resultant but I don't think the answer is logical ( i got 25 m/s). Can you please explain how to answer this?

Comment: You can use trigonometry to separate the final velocity into a vertical component and a horizontal component, and then add them normally. It sounds like when you used Pythagoras's theorem you were using the two velocities as the sides of your triangle.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let us build a coordinate system where +x is east, -x is west, +y is north, -y is south. So your initial velocity $v_i = (-22, 0) $ Your final speed is 12 m/s, but since you are traveling in the South West Direction, you need to use Pythagorean Theorem to find the vector components in the x-y coordinate system. 12 is the hypotenuse, so the legs have length $6\sqrt{2}$. Thus final velocity $v_f = (-6\sqrt{2},-6\sqrt{2})$.

Therefore $\Delta v = v_f - v_i = (-6\sqrt{2},-6\sqrt{2})- (-22, 0) = (22 - 6\sqrt{2},-6\sqrt{2})$

Comment: Thank you! Finally i just have to use he Pythagoras theory and use tan to get the angle!